# Fade transition after long period of time gets out of sync with its setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been trying to figure out why after a random amount of loops this function fades in multiple lines instead of one at a time. It seems to be that the setInterval gets out of sync. Everything looks correct to me and this is a question to find out what im doing wrong.

Also if there is anything here that you think i could do better that would benefit myself and others please do let me know as I am new to Jquery.

Update **** 
I only want one shown at one time the problem im having is that after a random amount of loops it shows more than one or all of them fading at different times.

```
$(function() {

var items = $('.top-header-fading-headings li');
var index = 0;

items.hide();

function fadingSlider() {


    $(items[index]).fadeIn(4000).fadeOut(4000);
    index++;
    if (index === items.length) {
        index = 0;
    }
}

fadingSlider();
setInterval( fadingSlider, 8000);
```

});

Html:

```
 <ul class="no-bullet top-header-fading-headings">
        <li><h5>Instant online feedback from outstanding Maths tutors</h5></li>
        <li><h5>Smart assessment, tracking and analysis</h5></li>
        <li><h5>Cutting edge tools for online tuition</h5></li>
    </ul>
```

[image]

Comment: do you want animation one after another?

Comment: Yeah, its already doing the animation however after a certain amount of intervals it shows multiple items instead of just one. Sorry I didn't make this clear

Comment: Yeah I thought the js was correct however look in the question again i've updated it with a image. after a random set of loops i get something like that showing instead of the items fading one at a time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use instead relevant animation method complete callback to call same function recursively:

```
$(function () {

    var items = $('.top-header-fading-headings li');
    var index = 0;

    items.hide();

    function fadingSlider() {


        $(items[index]).fadeIn(4000).fadeOut(4000, fadingSlider);//<<<<
        index++;
        if (index === items.length) {
            index = 0;
        }
    }

    fadingSlider();

});
```

### -jsFiddle-

Comment: This has seemed to work, Is it possible to explain why please?

Comment: Ya, this is a well known javascript behaviour that an interval/timeout goes out of sync. You can read about it: http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/

Comment: Brilliant thank you very much. Learnt something quite valuable from this

Comment: I was going to ask one thing. If i wanted to stop the fading on hover so the user could read the text in their own time how would you go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Or use `setTimeout` inside the function instead:

```
function fadingSlider() {


    $(items[index]).fadeIn(4000).fadeOut(4000);
    index++;
    if (index === items.length) {
        index = 0;
    }
    setTimeout( fadingSlider, 8000);
}

fadingSlider();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try with call back function, no need setInterval,

```
$(function() {

var items = $('.top-header-fading-headings li');
var index = 0;
items.hide();

function fadingSlider(index) {//pass index as parameter

    $(items[index]).fadeIn(4000).fadeOut(4000, function(){

        fadingSlider((index === items.length - 1)? 0 : ++index); //recursive call
    });

}

fadingSlider(0);//initiate animation    
});
```